# need popover over custom template cell of Angularjs ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angularjs ui grid with progress bar in first column and my grid options are shown below :

```
  ctrl.gridOptions = {};

ctrl.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        field: 'completeStatus',
        cellTemplate: '<span>{{row.entity.completeStatus}} % </span> <uib-progressbar value="row.entity.completeStatus"> </uib-progressbar>',
        width: 100
    },

    {
        field: 'invoiceNum'
    }
];
```

html:

```
<div id="regGrid" ui-grid="ctrl.gridOptions" class="reg-grid"></div>
```

Which is working fine. Now I want to display bootstrap popover upon hovering the first cell of the grid, I mean the cell with field `'completeStatus'`. Can any one help me how to configure it?

Answer (score 2):

Add popover attributes to your cell template and have a popover template located in your component html. Like this:

***Component HTML:***

This will be located at the bottom of your HTML just before the closing root `</div>`.

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="cellPopover.html">
        <div>Your popover Template</div>
    </script>
```

***Component Controller***:
Adding the popover attributes to your cell template.

```
ctrl.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        field: 'completeStatus',
        cellTemplate: '<div popover attributes><span>{{row.entity.completeStatus}} % </span> <uib-progressbar value="row.entity.completeStatus"> </uib-progressbar></div>',
        width: 100
    }
```

Where I wrote `popover attributes` you will place the actual attributes such as:
1. `uib-popover-template="'cellPopover.html'"`
2. `popover-trigger="mouseenter"`
3. `popover-placement="bottom"`